# Python dataframe: Extract week# from Date column using isocalendar()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have dataframe with `Date` column in the format `1/2/2014 16:00:00`. I convert it to `01-02-2014` using this code: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')`

I get the week# in a separate column  by
`df['Week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).week` but, I get warning saying that `.week` is deprecated and should use `isocalendar().week`instead.

**Question:**

I tried to operate `isocalendar().week` over the `Date` column but get error. Can someone point about how to use isocalendar() ?

[image]

Comment: I modified the code to implement this code: `df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.isocalendar().week` . It works fine EXCEPT that the date 31st Dec 2012 shows week# to be 1 which is incorrect, it shuld rather be 52 or something. See attached photo.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep on using `pd.to_datetime`

```py
df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.isocalendar().week
```

If you format the `Date` column to `'%d-%m-%Y'` this kind of day first representation, you can specify `dayfirst` argument

```py
df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.isocalendar().week
```

`isocalendar().week` uses the `%V` `strftime` parameter, you can also try others

- `%U` - Week number of the year (**Sunday** as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0. Examples: **00**, 01, …, 53
- `%W` - Week number of the year (**Monday** as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0. Examples: **00**, 01, …, 53
- `%V` - **ISO 8601 week** as a decimal number with Monday as the first day of the week. Week 01 is the week containing Jan 4. Examples: **01**, 02, …, 53

Ref: [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes | datetime — Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```py
df['WeekV'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%V')
df['WeekU'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%U')
df['WeekW'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%W')
```

Comment: Please see my comment above, and also the attached snapshot. isocalendar() seems to be giving wrong week# for 12/31/2012 date...

Comment: @Sinha See the update

Answer (score -1):

https://pythontic.com/datetime/datetime/isocalendar

> "As per ISO standard 8601 and ISO standard 2015, an ISO week has
> Thursday as the middle of the week. This means a new ISO year can
> start as early as 29th December or as late as 4th January of a regular
> calendar i.e, a Gregorian calendar."

Week 1 of ISO calendar year 2012 started on 12/30/2011, since the first Thursday of the year fell on 1/3. It's not quite in line with the Gregorian calendar